# Why does Ruby think there are 366 days in 100 AD?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, leap-year

The following expression returns '366' in Ruby, implying 100 AD is a leap year (which it is not):

```
(Date.ordinal(101) - Date.ordinal(100)).to_i
```

Same with DateTime.

However, `Date.leap?(100)` correctly returns `false`.

Same results for version 1.9.1. and 2.0.0.

What gives?  Should I file a bug report?

**Update**

Also, apparenly 1582 AD is 10 days short!

```
(Date.ordinal(1583) - Date.ordinal(1582)).to_i
 => 355
```

Comment: What time zone (country) are you using when testing? Spain, Portugal, Italy, France or Lithuania maybe? They skipped 10 days that year to change to the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Kyle, I suspect you didn't choose those two dates at random.  Trying to set us up, eh? :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Maybe he looped through looking for anomalies?

Comment: if you used the discordian calendar you wouldn't have this problem..

Answer (score 8):

According to Wikipedia, [100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100) was indeed a leap year and [1582](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1582) did indeed skip 10 days.

Comment: It depends on the calendar you're using.  For most of the world, 1582 was most certainly not 10 days shorter than most.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, prior to 1582-10-15, Ruby interprets dates as Julian calendar dates, instead of Gregorian calendar dates. More details here:

http://teleologi.blogspot.com/2013/05/ruby-times-dates-good-bad-and-so-on.html

Apparently not a bug, but definitely violates the principle of least surprise (at least in the eyes of this coder).

How confusing!

**Edit**

Debate about "reasonable defaults" aside, Ruby seems to quite flexible on these touchy issues of calendar-choice, compared to other languages. I've learned that the Date and DateTime constructors can receive a "reform date" constant, which determines when the transition from Julian to Gregorian calendar occurs.  The default is ITALY (1582-10-15), but ENGLAND is also an option (the jump occurs at 1752-09-14).

To avoid surprises from transitioning between calendars, I should have used the Gregorian calendar for all dates:

```
(Date.ordinal(i+1,1,Date::GREGORIAN) - Date.ordinal(i,1,Date::GREGORIAN)).to_i
 => 365
```

Also, `Date.leap?(100)` returned "false" because it is an alias of `Date.gregorian_leap?`. Meanwhile, `Date.julian_leap(100)` returns true.  To avoid surprises, probably best to use method version of leap?, which uses whichever reform date you've picked.

```
Date.new(100, 1, 1, Date::JULIAN).leap?
  => true

Date.new(100, 1, 1, Date::GREGORIAN).leap?
  => false
```

Comment: Yes, but nobody uses that very early version of Ruby any more.

Comment: @CarySwoveland What version were they using back then, anyway?  0.000001 or so? ;-)

Comment: It violates the principle of least surprise that the number of days for these years are correct?

Comment: @Cubic If the political decision of four countries to reform their calendars in 1582 is the "correct" decision, then yes you are right.  Obviously "surprise" is subjective, but it was surprising to me that the choice of calendar would change depending on the date, especially when the actual year in which this change occurred depends primarily on which King you deem the "correct" one.